# I'm trying to use gym_super_mario_bros and it's giving me this error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to use gym_super_mario_bros and I'm still in the first steps of the code in python but I don't understand why is it giving me this error

`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)`

no matter how many elements I try to unpack

here is the code

```
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
import gym_super_mario_bros
from gym_super_mario_bros.actions import SIMPLE_MOVEMENT


env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)

done = True
for step in range(100000):
    if done:
        env.reset()
    state, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    env.render()

env.close()
```

the error is in this line of code
`state, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())`

thank you in advance for your help

I tried to run super_mario using gym and get the random state of the game but it didn't happen and I get this error instead: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gym\_super\_mario\_bros (7.3.0) - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74060371/gym-super-mario-bros-7-3-0-valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected)

Comment: Basically, it seems they've added another variable called "truncated". So the line should be `state, reward, done, info, truncated = env.step(env.action_space.sample())`